# Javascript cannot target DOM elements from inside this PHP code

Tags: javascript, php

Turning the header red isn't what I'm trying to achieve, I was actually trying to run a jQuery code, but this is just to show that (maybe) targeting DOM elements is the problem because a simple alert() works.

Also, the Javascript code that isn't working here does work outside this if statement.

```
if(!empty($_POST['description'])) {
    $query = $con->prepare('insert into tasks (user_id, description) values (?,?)');
    $query->execute(array($_SESSION['user_id'], $_POST['description']));

    ?>
    <script>
        alert('hi');  //works
        document.querySelector('header').style.color = 'red';  //doesn't work
    </script>
    <?php   
}
```

Comment: It is not good practice to put js and php into one file.
But if <header> is under <script>, it is not in the DOM yet. So script can not find this element.

Comment: it's

seems like your script is running before loading jQuery. check your console for the error.

Comment: Vayrex, header is above this script.

Comment: It might be relevant that the submit form is on the same page as this code.

Comment: try to put your javascript code into $(document).ready or $(document).load

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript code is maybe executed before your header is rendered, be sure to launch this code after your footer.
You may also have more than one header element in your page and your querySelector targets the wrong.

Comment: header is above this script and the script does work if put immediately after the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

If your script executes prior to the header element being in the DOM, the querySelector will not be able to find it because it does not exist.

Try this to have the script exectute after the entire DOM has been parsed (e.g. everything between `<html>` ... `</html>`):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    document.querySelector('header').style.color = 'red';
});
```

Comment: This did not work. Header is above this script and the script does work if put immediately after the if statement.

Comment: Try executing the querySelector in your browser's developer tools console and see if it returns anything. If not then the header element does not exist or is being wiped out by some other script prior to yours executing.